# Pairing two RDD-s

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have two RDD-s, where one is a map of the other. For example:

```
RDD[Double] N;
RDD[Double] logN = N.map(x => Math.Log(x));
```

And I want to operate on matching pairs from both of them.
Something like this:

```
RDD[Double] NlogN = (N,logN).map((x,y) => x*y);
```

Is this kind of an operation available in spark?

Comment: If all you need is pairs then mapping directly could a better choice: `N.map(x => (x, Math.log(x)))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `zip`

```
N.zip(logN).map { case (x, y) => ... }
```